# Troubleshooting: ConcurrentModificationException when accessing MutableLiveData Object in Android

Tags: java, android

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException happened in MutableLiveData Object proxy design pattern

In android I have Class that named Exam , Exam Have a List of Question and each Question have a List of Answer , So I created ModelView Like :

```
private final MutableLiveData<Exam> liveExam;
...
    public MutableLiveData<Exam> getExam() {
        return liveExam;
    }
...
    public void updateQuestion(int nextOrPrevious) throws Exception {
        int indexOfQuestion = questionPosition.getValue() + nextOrPrevious;
        if (indexOfQuestion >= 0 && (exam.getQuestions().size() >= (indexOfQuestion))) {
            mlQuestionText.postValue(liveExam.getValue().getQuestions().get(indexOfQuestion).getText());
            questionPosition.postValue(indexOfQuestion);
            mlExamQuestionNumber.postValue(TextUtil.toPersian(String.format(formattedQuestionNumberAndEndNumber, liveExam.getValue().getQuestions().get(indexOfQuestion).getIndex(), exam.getQuestions().size())));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("No more Question here");
        }
    }
```

everything work fine , but when I call :questionViewModel.getQuestionPosition().getValue().getQuestions()
.get(questionPosition).getAnswers()
if update answer like blow :

```
Iterator<Answer> iterator = exam.getQuestions().get(questionPosition)
.getAnswers().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         Answer answer = iterator.next();
answer.setAnswer(answer.getId() == checkedId);
exam.getQuestions().get(questionPosition).getAnswers().set(indexAnswer, answer);
      indexAnswer++;
                    }
                        questionViewModel.getExam().postValue(exam);
                      try {
                      questionViewModel.updateQuestion(1);
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     }
       onUpdateQuestion();
```

I got an error for ConcurrentModificationException.

full print:

```
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
at ir.mehritco.megnatis.cattell.ui.question.QuestionFragment$4.onCheckedChanged(QuestionFragment.java:185)                                                                      at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:200)
at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:62)
at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:385)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:221)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:137)
at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:77)
at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:142)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

what happened here? and way I got this error?
I try some ways like store exam value in another Object and than post exam value or getQuestion from modelView as MutableLiveData but result as same!
My goal is :
Store answer(data) into answer(object)
so for this I need goto exam goto question list get question goto answer list get answer and updated

Comment: For you're iterator, have you tried `Iterator<Answer> iterator = new ArrayList<>(exam.getQuestions().get(questionPosition).getAnswers()).iterator()`?

Comment: yep same result

Comment: yes but not effected in live data, I will worked on it with his answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to modify collections while iterating except via the iterator. You can use `ListIterator` to do that:

```
ListIterator<Answer> iterator = exam.getQuestions()
        .get(questionPosition).getAnswers().listIterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Answer answer = iterator.next();
    answer.setAnswer(answer.getId() == checkedId);
    iterator.set(answer);
}
```

Or you could use an indexed loop instead of an iterator.

But in this case there's no point in calling `set()` at all, because you're not updating the `answer` reference, just the state of the object already in the list. So you can simplify this to a simple `for` loop or use `forEach()`:

```
exam.getQuestions()
        .get(questionPosition)
        .getAnswers()
        .forEach(a -> a.setAnswer(a.getId() == checkedId));
```

Comment: Answer not saving in the exam! use iterator.set(answer); but nothing work , the ConcurrentModificationException solved with your answer but no saving data into exam , what can i do?